# Trying to use property under repeat in applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm using my script to check a text file and send updates to me based on its changes.

Everytime I use the "property" tag inside of a "repeat" tag, it malfunctions and gives me the error: "Expected “end” but found “property”." I could use "set", but I don't want the value reset everytime the script is repeated. Thank you!

```
repeat

set theCEXRaw to read file "Macintosh HD:Users:adamvallorani:Desktop:CEX:CEXRaw"
set theGHS to paragraph 11 of theCEXRaw
set theBTC to paragraph 13 of theCEXRaw
set thePRICE to paragraph 26 of theCEXRaw

property oldBTC : 0

if theBTC > oldBTC then
    set theBTC to oldBTC
    set notif to "Your BTC has increased!"
    display notification notif with title "CEXalert"
end if


set BuyGHS to "0.02356001"
set SellGHS to "0.02361999"

if thePRICE > SellGHS then
    set notif2 to "Sell your GHS now!"
    display notification notif2 with title "CEXalert"
end if

if thePRICE < BuyGHS then
    set notif3 to "Buy some GHS now!"
    display notification notif3 with title "CEXalert"
end if

delay 2
end repeat
```

the "property" line is where the error ***-Expected “end” but found “property”-*** occurs

Answer (score 2):

Property statements are declarations that create pre-initialized global variables and must appear outside any handler code.  If you move the property statement to the top of your script AppleScript will accept it.  For the purposes of you example, you can simply say `set oldBTC to 0`.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere property can be used inside a subroutine to keep state each time the subroutine is called. Property will declare  the initial value first time subroutine is called and then any changes to value will be stored and next time sub-routine is run the script will NOT initialise the value declared in property statement. That is what I am looking for but I get the same error as in OP expecting end statement. I don't want a global variable I want a local variable that holds state. Any advice? Maybe I want local, will test with code now...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

At first glance I thought you might have a scoping problem because one must move the property statement outside of the repeat loop. To be effective properties must be defined outside of and before the repeat loop. But that is not exactly correct. Properties are values which retain their state after the script executes and so you will need to consider if this is the appropriate way to capture your value (the property value will be retained between script runs). It would be more appropriate to create a top level variable outside of the repeat statement using a line like:

```
set variablename to 0 -- or some other value
```

This will force the variable to reset each time the script runs and provide the proper values one would expect.

If you are trying to save a script property rather than a variable you can see some very good examples on how to do this at the following page of the [Applescript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/conceptual/ASLR_variables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH223-SW10). Also note the language for how these are scoped in Applescript.

[image: Scope Question]

If all else fails you can adopt some code like the following which will allow you to log the variable within the loop:

```
set wordList to words in "Where is the hammer?"
repeat with currentWord in wordList
    log currentWord
    if contents of currentWord is equal to "hammer" then
        display dialog "I found the hammer!"
    end if
end repeat
```

Please keep in mind that the variable must be set initially outside of the repeat loop and then changed as needed within the loop. A simpler way to accomplish this would be to use the value inside your repeat loop by assigning it to a temporary variable and logging the results to make sure you get exactly what is needed.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want it to reset each time. I want it to only be modified by Line 11 in this script

Comment: @adamitude - See revisions, hope that helps.